# Adding logs of jobs into a database with Talend

Tags: postgresql, talend

I am trying to import all the logs of the jobs running into a table in Postgres. I am using the components tLogCatcher and tStatCatcher and joining them to create a table with all the available data.

The job looks like this:

[image]

Inside the tMap, I am joining the two sources from logcatcher and statcatcher on the pid and the job name and try to merge the results to have them combined in a table:

[image]

However whenever the job fails I get nulls in the logcatcher output, even if there are error messages:

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3696
[statistics] connected
2017-02-03 13:51:07|PR7710|PR7710|PR7710|6981|NASIA|Master_ETL_Job|_52dYEJUvEeaqS8phzVFskQ|0.1|Default||begin||
Exception in component tFileInputDelimited_1
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/nasiantalla/Documents/keychain.csv (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at org.talend.fileprocess.TOSDelimitedReader.<init>(TOSDelimitedReader.java:88)
    at org.talend.fileprocess.FileInputDelimited.<init>(FileInputDelimited.java:164)
    at nasia.master_etl_job_0_1.Master_ETL_Job.tFileInputDelimited_1Process(Master_ETL_Job.java:796)
    at nasia.master_etl_job_0_1.Master_ETL_Job.runJobInTOS(Master_ETL_Job.java:6073)
    at nasia.master_etl_job_0_1.Master_ETL_Job.main(Master_ETL_Job.java:5879)
2017-02-03 13:51:08|PR7710|PR7710|PR7710|NASIA|Master_ETL_Job|Default|6|Java Exception|tFileInputDelimited_1|java.io.FileNotFoundException:/Users/nasiantalla/Documents/keychain.csv (No such file or directory)|1
2017-02-03 13:51:08|PR7710|PR7710|PR7710|6981|NASIA|Master_ETL_Job|_52dYEJUvEeaqS8phzVFskQ|0.1|Default||end|failure|890
[statistics] disconnected
Job Master_ETL_Job endet am 13:51 03/02/2017. [exit code=1]
```

And in my table the data I get are like this:

[image]

Do you see something that I might have missed? I tried with all different joins in the tMap but it doesn't seem to work and I dont understand why..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tStatCatcher` and `tLogCatcher` do not work when joined with a `tMap`.  I cannot give a definitive answer as to why, but I think its related to the special functionality involved in 'catching' the errors and stats, and is likely a timing issue.  The log catcher for instance will only catch an error while the stats can catch stats on every component.

I recommend writing to separate tables and joining on those tables to produce reports.  As a matter of fact Talend has this functionality built in so you do not even need to provide your own `tStatCatcher` and `tLogCatcher` components in each job.

You must first create the AMC database structure then go to file-->edit project settings--> job settings -->  stats and logs.  Choose the 'on database' option.  Then Talend will automatically log stats, errors and flows to the AMC db.  You can report off this db.
[image]

[image]

Comment: wow, that's amazing, I didnt know Talend could log automatically! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

They are 3 reasons for that :

- `tLogCatcher` does not provide logs if there is no `tDie` or `tWarn`, and i think this is your case.
- It's not necessary that `tLogCatcher` and `tStatCatcher` provide their data at the same time, because their are triggered by different events. So join will not match.
- From functional prespective, joining the 2 flow does not make sense, they are fully independent.

I recommand you to dump these flows into different tables, and this can be achieved implicitly without using any component and without development, see [here](https://help.talend.com//pages/viewpage.action?pageId=267109917).